# Regarding "this" and "this.value"

Tags: javascript, html, css, pointers, web

I am at the beginning of designing a web page. I was trying to design a login page and searched for the same and found something but I am confused with a line

```
onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value='' ">
```

But I am confused with `this` and `this.value` and also the `if` statement.

Comment: In `html5` the `placeholder` attribute will do this internally and better. So since most of the current browsers support `html5` you just need to add `placeholder="Username"` to your `<input>` element and remove the code you have in your question. Unless you are targeting a certain browser which does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
"if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'"
```

"this" refers to the current element.
"this.value" refers to the value the current element has.

As for the if statement, for onBlur it means that when the user leaves that field it will ask if the current value of the element is blank ('') if it is true then it will change the value to 'Username'.

Answer (score 0):

HTML event listeners, such as `onBlur` and `onFocus` takes a "JavaScript function" that activates when the respective action is triggered. On an HTML element, `this` refers to the element itself, while `this.value` is the value of the input element. The `onBlur` attribute triggers when the user leaves the field and the `if` statement checks whether the field is empty, and if so, set it to "Username." The `onFocus` on the other hand, is the exact opposite, triggering when the user enters the field and clears it if the value already is "Username."

I would actually advise against doing this if possible, and to replace it with `placeholder="Username"` instead, which does practically the same thing.

Read more about HTML events [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/ref_eventattributes.asp), or [learn more about placeholders](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp). I would also suggest looking more into HTML and JavaScript in general.